# Performance difference with Where condition in subquery/cte

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

Is there a performance difference for applying the where condition to a subquery data source compared to applying it at the joined statement?  Is there a difference between these in performance?

Let's say I have two hive tables A and B which are both partitioned on the field **date**.

```
WITH table_A AS (
  SELECT date, some_info FROM some_table WHERE date = '2020-12-11'
),
table_B AS (
  SELECT date, some_other_info FROM some_other_table WHERE date = '2020-12-11'
)

SELECT table_A.*, table_B.some_other_info FROM table_A INNER JOIN table_B
```

Is that query's performance the same as the following?

```
WITH table_A AS (
  SELECT table_A, some_info FROM some_table
),
table_B AS (
  SELECT date, some_other_info FROM some_other_table 
)

SELECT table_A.*, table_B.some_other_info FROM table_A INNER JOIN table_B WHERE table_A.date = '2020-12-11'
```

Comment: Why are you using CTEs at all for this query?

Comment: Just a toy example to demo the question.  You're right that CTEs are needed in this specific example.

Comment: CTEs in Hive have been gradually improving since their introduction, so I guess the answer will depend on your Hive version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is:  it depends.  That said, I'm a fan of putting the filtering as early as possible in the processing.  As a general rule, it can't hurt.

What does it depend on?  Well is the CTE materialized?  That is, is it saved to an intermediate "table"?  This, alas, is controlled by a setting `hive.optimize.cte.materialize.threshold`.  If the CTE is materialized, then you definitely want it filtered in the CTE>

On the other hand, materialization might lose other beneficial information about the original data -- such as partitioning schemes.  So, once again, it depends.

I do think that a CTE referenced only once is not materialized with the default settings.  So, in that context, it doesn't make a difference.